# Json.NET LINQ query for single JProperty on JArray of JObjects

Tags: linq, json.net

I have a JArray with this configuration

```
[
    {
        "name" : "text",
        "age" : 32
    },
    {
        "name" : "text2",
        "age" : 33
    },
]
```

and I want to use LINQ query to select a JArray containing JObjects with just the key value of a specified given key.

For example:

```
GetCollectionOfPropertiesByKey("name");
```

this would result in:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "text"
    },
    {
        "name" : "text2"
    },
]
```

using the same logic,

```
GetCollectionOfPropertiesByKey("age");
```

would result in:

```
[
    {
        "age" : 32
    },
    {
        "age" : 33
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify whether you needed case-invariant filtering for properties by name, so here is an extension method with an optional `StringComparison` argument:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JArray GetCollectionOfPropertiesByKey(this JArray array, string key, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.Ordinal)
    {
        if (array == null)
            return null;
        var query = array
            // Filter out array items that are not objects
            .OfType<JObject>()
            // Select the value JToken with the specified key using the specified StringComparison
            .Select(o => o.GetValue(key, comparison))
            // Filter for null (property was not found)
            .Where(v => v != null)
            // And select a new JObject containing just the JPropery parent of the selected value
            .Select(v => new JObject(v.Parent));
        return new JArray(query);
    }
}
```

If a case-insensitive match is required, pass `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Notes:

- The query filters for all items in the input array that are of type `JObject`, then uses [`JObject.GetValue(String, StringComparison)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_GetValue_1.htm) to get the corresponding value by key name.
- Then, if a value is found, it constructs a new `JObject` using the [parent](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parent.htm) of the selected value, which should be a `JProperty`.
- If case insensitivity is never required, you could simplify the query a bit by using [`JObject.Property(String)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Property.htm) to get the `JProperty` by key name, and then constructing a `JObject` containing it, like so:

  ```
  var query = array
      // Filter out array items that are not objects
      .OfType<JObject>()
      // Select the JProperty with the specified key
      .Select(o => o.Property(key))
      // Filter for null (property was not found)
      .Where(p => p != null)
      // And select a new JObject with just this property
      .Select(p => new JObject(p));
  ```

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9GvGIX).

Comment: It's just perfect and beautifully explained!! Thank you